# How to add application to windows startup sending arguments in a .net WPF application?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows

I have a .net WPF desktop application that I developped using Visual Studio and I want to add this application to windows startup. Windows startup should run this application sending an argument "Start" so that program will know that it is started after logon instead of user. I have seen some solutions for adding this app to start up but could not find any example that starts app with arguments.
Example code fragment:

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", true);
key.SetValue("Your Application Name", Application.ExecutablePath);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set the value not to the `Application.ExecutablePath` only, but with the params itself appended. Example from my registry:

```
Key:
MicrosoftEdgeAutoLaunch_AC4772F08F551843066B27D28EB56714

Value:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --no-startup-window --win-session-start /prefetch:5
```

Comment: Then, I should do something like this I guess:
key.SetValue("Your Application Name", Application.ExecutablePath + " Start")
am I right?

Comment: @KaanÇağhan yes, and also it's wise to enclose executable path into quotes, like in me example above (otherwise, if the path contains spaces it would not work as expected)